# Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles returns the wrong directory

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# project and I am using the following code:

```
string rootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

However, when I look at the rootPath, it's set to C:\Program Files (x86).

Why would do it this as there is an `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` which I would have thought would have returned the above.

Comment: What bitness is your process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your project is currently targeting the `x86` platform, both of those enum values will return the `Program Files(x86)` directory.

Change the target platform for your project to `x64`, and `SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` should return the `Program Files` directory instead.

Comment: Ah yes, not sure why it was specifically set to target x86. I've set it to target Any CPU and now its working. Thanks for your help

Comment: +1. @Boardy - Note that "Any CPU" may not be enough - make sure "prefer 32-bit" property of the project is not checked (default is checked).

Answer (score 6):

I have a scenario where i could not change the target of the executing assembly. So i use this method to get always the x64 (also when running in 32bit):

```
var programFilesX64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion")?.GetValue("ProgramFilesDir");
```